# What is causing my "move chart" macro to result in error "the specified dimension is not valid for the current chart type"?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

My code is below. The macro is supposed to move all charts from the active sheet to a new sheet. It works fine IF I manually click on a chart with my mouse before running the macro. However, if I don't do that I get the error **"the specified dimension is not valid for the current chart type"**. Any idea why?

**Edit: this is the line that causes the error:**

```
objChart.Chart.Location xlLocationAsObject, strNewSheet
```

-

```
Sub MoveThoseCharts()
'moves each chart on the currently active sheet to a new sheet named "final charts"
    Dim strNewSheet As String
    Dim objTargetWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim objWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim objChart As Object

    Set objWorksheet = ActiveSheet
    'Create a new sheet
    strNewSheet = "Final Charts"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(Before:=Application.Worksheets(1)).Name = strNewSheet
    Set objTargetWorksheet = Application.Worksheets(strNewSheet)

    'move each chart
           For Each objChart In objWorksheet.ChartObjects
               objChart.Chart.Location xlLocationAsObject, strNewSheet
           Next objChart

    objTargetWorksheet.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: Are there more than one type of chart in the sheet?  If so, have you tried an if-statement for `objchart.charttype` to ensure you're only selecting the desired chart types?

Comment: @Cyril all charts on the sheet are the same exact type

Comment: @BigBen I updated the post to show which line throws the error

Comment: What type of chart? Can't repro the error based on the info provided.

Comment: When looping over a collection with `For Each` it's sometimes best not to remove items from the collection - have you tried a `For i = objWorksheet.ChartObjects.Count to 1 Step -1` loop instead?

Comment: @BigBen it's a combo chart: data series 1 is a column chart and data series 2 is a line graph. There's also a data table (not sure if that's relevant)

Comment: Hmm... still no dice. I recreated some combo charts with a data table, and had no problem.